# [ROS2] Failed to load entry point 'launch'

Tags: ros2, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I wanted to start my launch file from command line with following command

```
ros2 launch <pkg_name> <file>
```

now i got this error:

```
Failed to load entry point 'launch': cannot import name 'get_typed_value' from 'launch.frontend.type_utils' (/home/lwnmil2/develop_ws/install/launch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/frontend/type_utils.py)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/bin/ros2", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('ros2cli==0.9.7', 'console_scripts', 'ros2')()
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ros2cli/cli.py", line 39, in main
    add_subparsers_on_demand(
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ros2cli/command/__init__.py", line 236, in add_subparsers_on_demand
    extension = command_extensions[name]
KeyError: 'launch'
```

When I open the help of the ros2 command the same error message is shown and there is no entry for the ros2 command:

```
ros2 -h


    Failed to load entry point 'launch': cannot import name 'get_typed_value' from 'launch.frontend.type_utils' (/home/lwnmil2/develop_ws/install/launch/lib/python3.8/site-packages/launch/frontend/type_utils.py)
usage: ros2 [-h] Call `ros2 <command> -h` for more detailed usage. ...

ros2 is an extensible command-line tool for ROS 2.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit

Commands:
  action     Various action related sub-commands
  bag        Various rosbag related sub-commands
  component  Various component related sub-commands
  daemon     Various daemon related sub-commands
  doctor     Check ROS setup and other potential issues
  interface  Show information about ROS interfaces
  lifecycle  Various lifecycle related sub-commands
  multicast  Various multicast related sub-commands
  node       Various node related sub-commands
  param      Various param related sub-commands
  pkg        Various package related sub-commands
  run        Run a package specific executable
  security   Various security related sub-commands
  service    Various service related sub-commands
  topic      Various topic related sub-commands
  wtf        Use `wtf` as alias to `doctor`

  Call `ros2 <command> -h` for more detailed usage.
```

What is broken on my system? and how can i fix it?
I use Ubuntu 20.04 with foxy

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/359106/%5Bros2%5D-failed-to-load-entry-point-%27launch%27/) by [lmiller](https://answers.ros.org/users/48153/lmiller/) on ROS Answers with karma: 219 on 2020-08-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [drewbeller](https://answers.ros.org/users/96414/drewbeller/) on 2022-02-08**:
Seeing the same issue, I don't have a package called *launch* though

it was working previously in my environment before but then stopped and i'm not sure what changed. `test` is also not being found. I've tried initializing my workspace and packages from scratch but still have the same issue

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2022-02-11**:
@drewbeller Please do not post answers that are not actually answers. I've converted your answer to a comment. If you have a new question, please open a new question. Thanks!

https://wiki.ros.org/Support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had a package called *launch* in my develop workspace so ROS had a name conflict
I removed it and now it works

---

Originally posted by [lmiller](https://answers.ros.org/users/48153/lmiller/) with karma: 219 on 2020-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0